# Microsoft reporting parameters not reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I have some very customized reports that I designed using `Microsoft Reporting rdlc` files. In first report I use **43** parameters so:

`R_1_1`,`R_1_2`,`R_1_3`,`R_1_4`,`R_1_5`,`R_1_6`,`R_2_1`,`R_2_2`,...

In second report I have **78** parameters so:

`R_1_1`,`R_1_2`,`R_1_3`,`R_1_4`,`R_1_5`,`R_1_6`,`R_1_7`,`R_1_8`,`R_2_1`,`R_2_2`,...

and I use this code for bind reports:

```
this.ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = BaseAddress + drpReportNumber.SelectedValue.Trim() + ".rdlc";
    this.ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

    this.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", new DataTable("DataSet1"));
    this.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource);
    this.ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

    if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            ReportParameter p = new ReportParameter(parameters[i].ParameterName, parameters[i].ParameterValue);
            this.ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I create first report then I want also create the second report, report viewer raise this error:

> {"An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'R_1_7' that is not defined in this report."}

I have two questions;

1. Is there any limitation for parameters count?
2. I think when I bind ReportViewer to first report it does not contains `R_1_7`, and in second times parameters list does not reset and it use first parameters list. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: It seems that you are not changing the `LocalReport` properly. I rember to you that the `ReportParameters` are defined in the report (the .rldc file) and not in the `DataSet`. I could asusme that the code you have snipped is from a cicle in which you are increment the variable `drpReportNumber`. Use the debug, and check that you are using the right report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found [this blog post](http://www.codeease.com/a-problem-when-dynamically-switch-rdlc-in-reportviewer.html) that seems to have exactly your problem.

Add this before your `this.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();`:

```
this.ReportViewer.Reset();
```